# Nuxt reCAPTCHA v3 no data returned from fetch SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: nuxt.js, fetch, recaptcha

I am trying to implement reCAPTCHA v3 in a Nuxt website. I am using @nuxt/recaptcha v1.1.2. I've tried many different formats for the API call, like axios.post, this.$axios.$post, and now I am using fetch.

But the JSON response from fetch is always empty. Very frequently, the error is

**SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input**

The original article I copied code from is [here](https://the-blog.hashnode.dev/integrate-google-recaptcha-into-your-nuxtjs-project).

I wrote the following code:

```js
    async verifyCaptcha () {
      try {
        const token = await this.$recaptcha.execute()

        // const url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' + process.env.SECRET_KEY + '&response=' + token
        const url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'

        const data = {
          secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
          response: token
        }

        return fetch(url, {
          method: 'POST',
          mode: 'no-cors',
          body: qs.stringify(data),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          }
        })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
            return data
          })
      } catch (error) {
        return error
      }
    }
```

Any ideas or comments are welcome.